# JFreeChart gridline? paint set

Tags: colors, jfreechart, gridlines

[image: Chart]

I have this chart and I want the line at `0` to be WHITE instead of BLACK, but I'm not sure which property I have to change.

I've already tried:

```
((CategoryPlot) chart.getPlot()).getDomainAxis().setAxisLinePaint(Color.WHITE);
((CategoryPlot) chart.getPlot()).setDomainGridlinePaint(Color.WHITE);
((CategoryPlot) chart.getPlot()).setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.WHITE);
```

And none of them seem to be what I need. I also tried searching for a solution, but I'm not sure what this line is called exactly, so I don't really know what to search for. Can someone please tell me which property I need to set to WHITE?

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line drawn perpendicular to the range axis (y-axis) at the value zero is referred to in JFreeChart as the `rangeZeroBaseline`.  The method you need is:

http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/CategoryPlot.html#setRangeZeroBaselinePaint-java.awt.Paint-